# Version compatible issue in opencart extension

Tags: opencart

I want to use multi file upload extension in opencart

I have tried the extension

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=21861&filter_search=image%20upload&filter_license=0

But it is giving version compatible error. My opencart version is 2.0.3.1 is there any other extension to upload multiple images

Or any modification in this version

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the extension you are using does not support your Opencart version (2.3.0.1)

It's a good practice to always check for OpenCart extension compatibility before installing it. I did a little research and [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_download_id=41&filter_search=multiple%20image%20upload) are few extensions which will help you upload multiple images.

Also check extension http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8221&filter_search=image%20upload&filter_license=0

I hope this helps you.